# How to update values in android app using firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi Please find the structure of firebase DB?

[image]

Now let's say, we want to update **fName** and **lName** from **-LcKJ14wv-Y46QER1V-
0**

How to update them so only these values are updated and **no new values are added** in the database?

**Code we have written**

```
queryToGetData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(AppData.STUDENTS)
                    .orderByChild("studentUnique").equalTo(user.getUid()).limitToFirst(1);
            queryToGetData.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        db.push().setValue(ss);
                        Common.alertDialog("Added","Profile Details saved", StudentProfile.this);
                    } else {
                        db.setValue(ss);
                        Common.alertDialog("Oops","Profile Updated", StudentProfile.this);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Common.alertDialog("Oops","Something went wrong!", StudentProfile.this);
                }
            });
```

**What this piece of code is doing?**

*when running update for the first time(the whole collection is empty)*

[image]

*when running update for the second time(same user)

[image]

*when running update for the third time(same user)*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would suggest to restructure your db like this for much simpler query.

```
students
    QslkALDJFLDFLFk(this is the student unique key or the uid)
        emailAddress:
        fName:
```

Then use `updateChildren()` to update specific fields.

```
Student student = new Student("firstName", "lastName");
Map<String, Object> values = student.toMap();

queryToGetData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child(AppData.STUDENTS).child(user.getUid())
    .updateChildren(values);
```

You can read the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields)

Comment: how do I set uid as document key using android? sorry very new to firebase

Comment: FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); Access user id by user.getUid(): You can then put the user id value in building query, .child(user.getUid()). Sorry i could not clarify this more, im using my phone in this comment

Comment: hey, i'm able to GET the id but I want to SET that id as document id!

Comment: Ex. Database.child(“students).child(user.getUid()).setValue()

Comment: accepted the answer for long time approach :) thanks for helping out

Answer (score 0):

i am doing this way ;-

```
DatabaseReference receiverUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(chatListTableName)
                .child(userId)
                .child(firebaseUser.getUid());

        receiverUserRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    receiverUserRef.child("time").setValue(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                } else {
                    receiverUserRef.child("id").setValue(firebaseUser.getUid());
                    receiverUserRef.child("isGroup").setValue("false");
                    receiverUserRef.child("time").setValue(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: leave a comment if any query.

Comment: i do want to check if row exists, if it does it has to update otherwise add new row with following details

Comment: Hi, db.child("key").child("emailAddress").setValue(studentEmailAddress.getText().toString());

How do i get key value of firebase row key?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what @elbert rivas said regarding the use of the `uid` to identify your users rather than a pushed id. In that case, to update a user object, you don't need a query. However, if can't change your database structure, you can still update a user object like in the following lines of code:

```
queryToGetData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(AppData.STUDENTS)
                .orderByChild("studentUnique").equalTo(user.getUid());
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("fName", "newFirstName");
            map.put("lName", "newLastName");
            ds.getRef().updateChildren(map);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
queryToGetData.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

See, I have removed the `.limitToFirst(1)` because the `uid` of a user are unique. So even if we remove that method call, you'll still get a single result.